# How to hide sensitive information from TFS Checkin

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I would like to evaluate the performance of a new developer before bringing him on full time.  However I would like certain customer names, other sensitive data within our visual studio solution to be "obfuscated" to him so that when he gets latest, etc., he does not see this sensitive information.  Is there any way to rename certain strings when he checks code out to make certain strings appear as something else, but make it so that when I check code out these strings are replaced with their actual values?

Comment: No. The solution to this is called an NDA.

Comment: You can't do this in TFS with strings in code however you can have your CI/CD system insert sensitive data such as passwords and API keys into the config files during build

Comment: CI/CD insertions is a good solution, thanks!  @DanielMann, an NDA is no solution for my use case as the developer is in a far away country. The costs and unpredictability would make this a terrible solution to be quite frank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is not such a feature in TFS.

Alternatively, you can create a new branch. And hide the sensitive information in this branch. Then let the new developer work on this specific branch. See [Branch folders and files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branch-folders-files?view=azure-devops).

You can also change the security settings to allow the developer to access to this branch only. Go to project Settings-->Version Control(or Repositories) See below:

[image]